# Logistic LASSO with observation weights in HDM in R

Tags: r, lasso, glmnet

I'm trying to run a logistic LASSO regression using the `HDM` package in R (`hdm::rlassologit`), but because my dataset is very large with almost a billion observations, any attempt to build it into a matrix to feed into the function crashes the R session.

I can successfully use `glmnet` to run a logistic LASSO with observation weights, turning the almost billion row dataset into only several thousand but I am interested in implementing the penalty lambda used in `HDM`, which isn't directly supported by `glmnet`.

Does anyone know of a way to use observation weights with `rlassologit`? Or, alternatively, grouped as "successes" and "failures", similar to how the `glm` function allows to feed two vectors into the left-hand side of the formula using `cbind`? Any ideas will be very much appreciated!